# Disable div click on Ajax start and re-enable it on Ajax complete

Tags: jquery

I need a div to be disabled (so that it no longer receives click) on start of an Ajax request and re-enable it on Ajax complete. I also want a loading gif to be shown during the process. I think that this could be accomplished using `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`. But, if I am correct these would fire for any Ajax request that start or stops. Here comes the problem. I have multiple div's on a page and anyone of these could trigger an Ajax request. How can I disable/enable the "specific div" that was clicked and how can I display/hide it's corresponding loading gif either using `ajaxStart`, `ajaxStop` or any other method. Please note that if this involves binding/unbinding of click event then the method suggested needs to maintain compatibility with jQuery `on()`.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="button white"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>
<div class="button white"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>
<div class="button white"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>
```

The Javascript for Ajax looks like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url     : ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
        context : this,
        type    :'POST',
        async   : true,
        cache   : false,
        timeout : 1000,
        data    : { action : 'test_action' },
        success : function(response) {
            if (response == 1) {
                $(this).toggleClass('white').toggleClass('green');
            }
        },
        error   : function() {
            alert(error);
        }
   });
});
```

Regards, John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to disable button, simply change current class button.

you can use this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$(this).removeClass('button').addClass('disabledbutton');

$.ajax({
    url     : ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
    context : this,
    type    :'POST',
    async   : true,
    cache   : false,
    timeout : 1000,
    data    : { action : 'test_action' },
    success : function(response) {
        if (response == 1) {
            $(this).toggleClass('white').toggleClass('green');
            $(this).removeClass('disabledbutton').addClass('button');
        }
    },
    error   : function() {
        alert(error);
    }

   });
});
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. removeClass does not remove the .button class. However, addClass works. Could this possibly because .button is used as the selector in on() event?

Comment: @John sorry dear. this is wrong: .removeClass('.button') and this is correct: .removeClass('button') i edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Simply creating some helper functions for enabling / disabling functions works well for this. Just call the disable fn on click, and call the enable function upon ajax success.

```
function disableButton( button ) {
  //disable actions
}

function enableButton( button ) {
  //enable actions
}

$('body').on('click', '.button', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    disableButton( $(this) );

    $.ajax({
        url     : ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
        context : this,
        type    :'POST',
        async   : true,
        cache   : false,
        timeout : 1000,
        data    : { action : 'test_action' },
        success : function(response) {
            if (response == 1) {
                $(this).toggleClass('white').toggleClass('green');
                enableButton( $(this) );
            }
        },
        error   : function() {
            alert(error);
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. Could you suggest what code should I use within the functions to make this work. That's essentially what I was looking for as an answer.